# Virtualization / Cloud-Stack fingerprinting from running VM

Tags: virtualization, cloud-computing, fingerprinting

How can the host environment (not just the OS) be identified from a running guest VM. To determine what the underlying host and virtualization stacks being used actually are. I.e. whether there's a VMWare, Cisco, OpenStack or other IaaS solution powering it.

I already know of [imvirt](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html) and [virt-what](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html) but they don't provide a lot more info than the basic type of virtualization used, like KVM, Xen, etc.

How can I dig a level deeper and find out more specifics about the underlying stack and products being used. Are there any known reliable fingerprinting approaches?

- MAC address look ups don't seem to work
- Searching for Hardware vendor names in the output of `dmidecode` seems not reliable as these names are often customized and branded by the company running the infrastructure.

How reliable are `lspci`results like:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio network device
00:04.0 SCSI storage controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio block device
```

Does this mean that VMWare on Red Hat is used? Or does it mean nothing at all as these virtual devices can be used by anyone?

Thanks

PS: There is a related question here but quite old (from 08) and not quite the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application

Answer (score -1):

About trying to identify the virtualization stack, a KVM host can be identified by issuing a combination of some commands like these:
dmesg |grep KVM
lscpu |grep Hypervisor (it should return Hypervisor vendor: KVM)

You can even try to fingerprint the host with nmap with OS detection option (nmap -O host_to_check_ip), it can give you some information about the MAC address.

I think the same can be done to try to identify VMware hosts and other kind of hypervisors too.

Comment: Please read my post again.

Comment: Ok, sorry if my post before was unclear.As in the discussion you posted from 2008 the answer is:
there are not reliable fingerprinting ways to determine the underlying stack. 
(unless you exploit some vulns on the Hypervisor for a guest-to-host virtual machine escape).
There are only some methods though you can try to use toghether to try to have the "big picture".
For example:from the lspci output you posted, I would try to get more details using the Metasploit module 
auxiliary/scanner/vmware/esx_fingerprint to see if the host is running on VMware,but as said before
it's not 100% accurate.